# Query regarding tracking tags in Omniture

Tags: tags, adobe-analytics

I have a query regarding the tracking of a tag in Omniture Sitecatalyst.

Here's the scenario.

Suppose i have an article page, with some tags defined. These are the tags, which a user would when search, will be brought to the article, associated with the tags.

How can I track these tags in omniture. Like what are the top most searched tags. Can we also get details of the reports associated with those tags.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you should use a list prop (e.g. assign `prop1` for it and check the box to mark it as a list prop) or list var (e.g. `list1`). But read the documentation to understand how the data is attributed in reports. The list prop is fairly easy to understand because it is hit scoped, but the list var's scope and attribution model is a lot more complex.